# Pages cannot be acces by googebot

Tags: nuxt.js

We build a new site. Besides the homepage all other pages cannot be accessed by googlebot (google webmaster tool) but can be acccessed normal by browser.  Als so the source code in the browser looks strange.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/f0f7848.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/49ed805.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/1c443d6.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/ea7926b.js" as="script">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="__nuxt"><style>#nuxt-loading{background:#fff;visibility:hidden;opacity:0;position:absolute;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;flex-direction:column;animation:nuxtLoadingIn 10s ease;-webkit-animation:nuxtLoadingIn 10s ease;animation-fill-mode:forwards;overflow:hidden}@keyframes nuxtLoadingIn{0%{visibility:hidden;opacity:0}20%{visibility:visible;opacity:0}100%{visibility:visible;opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes nuxtLoadingIn{0%{visibility:hidden;opacity:0}20%{visibility:visible;opacity:0}100%{visibility:visible;opacity:1}}#nuxt-loading>div,#nuxt-loading>div:after{border-radius:50%;width:5rem;height:5rem}#nuxt-loading>div{font-size:10px;position:relative;text-indent:-9999em;border:.5rem solid #f5f5f5;border-left:.5rem solid #34c38f;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);-ms-transform:translateZ(0);transform:translateZ(0);-webkit-animation:nuxtLoading 1.1s infinite linear;animation:nuxtLoading 1.1s infinite linear}#nuxt-loading.error>div{border-left:.5rem solid #ff4500;animation-duration:5s}@-webkit-keyframes nuxtLoading{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}@keyframes nuxtLoading{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}</style><script>window.addEventListener("error",function(){var e=document.getElementById("nuxt-loading");e&&(e.className+=" error")})</script><div id="nuxt-loading" aria-live="polite" role="status"><div>Loading...</div></div></div><script>window.__NUXT__={config:{_app:{basePath:"/",assetsPath:"/_nuxt/",cdnURL:null}},staticAssetsBase:"/_nuxt/static/1687954917"}</script>
  <script src="/_nuxt/f0f7848.js"></script><script src="/_nuxt/49ed805.js"></script><script src="/_nuxt/1c443d6.js"></script><script src="/_nuxt/ea7926b.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

What are we doing wrong?

best remco